# What is the technical name for this bitwise operation?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, bit-manipulation

I'm converting some old Visual Basic logic in an Access Database to JavaScript.  There are functions that get and set a value that is -- for the lack of a better term -- in "bitwise" format.  I had to get out a pencil and some paper to reverse engineer what the responsible functions are doing.

**What is the technical term for the bitwise operation I am conducting below?**   Please keep in mind that the total number of slots *could* be higher (e.g. 15 instead of 6).

```
---All scheduling slots selected, decimal value = 126

Slot    Selected?   Formula
-----   ----------  ----------
1       1           0 + 2^1 = 2
2       1           2 + 2^2 = 6
3       1           6 + 2^3 = 14
4       1           14 + 2^4 = 30
5       1           30 + 2^5 = 62
6       1           62 + 2^6 = 126

 integer value = 126


--Custom scheduling slots selected, decimal value = 82

Slot    Selected?   Formula
-----   ----------  ----------
1       1           0 + 2^1 = 2
2       0
3       0
4       1           2 + 2^4 = 18
5       0
6       1           18 + 2^6 = 82

integer value = 82
```

Comment: This is just converting a binary number to decimal. Except you seem to be missing a slot 0. Binary `1111110` = `126` and `1010010` = `82`

Comment: You can do this in js with `parseInt('111111' , 2) <<  1` *// 126* `parseInt('101001',2) <<  1` *// 82*

Comment: @MarkMeyer am I correct to interpret this as, "convert the integer to base 2, then do a 'zero fill left shift' because you forgot your first zero, and I don't care about contiguous 0's on the right"?

Comment: @raydlevel5 yes it's "parse this string as a base 2 integer" It then uses `<< 1` to shift it one place to the right to account for the missing zero in order to get the expected results.

Comment: One thing they are called are flags. `Msgbox 5 and &h1` returns 1 showing bit 0 is set (2^0 = 1). `Msgbox 6 and &h1` returns 0 showing bit 0 is not set. So one tests for 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ..., n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are usually called **BitFlags** (storing boolean values as individual bits in a word), it's a special case of BitFields: to address arbitrary widths of bits for different values.

It's quite possible it has multiple names, as it's fairly obvious and is probably rediscovered independently all the time as people learn to program (that's how i discovered it).

Rather than calculating the numerical value it's more common to construct a bitfield using SHIFTs and ORs, and destruct them using SHIFTs and ANDs - since this is more literal, intuitive (and faster); The numerical value is just a side effect of interpreting the whole word as an integer. i.e:

```js
// construct
x = 0;
// set bit 0
x |= true << 0;
// set bit 1
x |= false << 1;
// set bit 2
x |= true << 2;

x // 5

// destruct
x = 3
// get bit 0
!! (x >> 0 & 1); // true
// get bit 1
!! (x >> 1 & 1); // true
// get bit 2
!! (x >> 2 & 1); // false
```

Additionally, if you are sending the data through an inefficient format e.g text or JSON over AJAX, then you will want to encode the resulting number to maximise the bits packed into each character... using `x.toString(36)` will let you store 5 bits (2^5 = 32) in a single char (a-z0-9). Or you can squeeze out another bit if you use `String.fromCharCode(x + 32)` - if you take a look at the ASCII table then you can use all the printable chars in the range 32-127 = 95, which is enough values for 6 bits (2^6 = 64), but not 7 (2^7 = 128). Attempting to use more than 6 bits will result in some combinations outputting multi-byte UTF8 chars which is probably not worth the encoding overhead (they will appear as one char but actually use 2-4 bytes).